# CSS: nav bar drop down menu fixed vs sticky unintended behavior

Tags: css

I seem to know just enough to get in trouble here with CSS. Everything worked fine until I tried to scroll. The nav bar drop down behaves wonderfully on a page that doesn't scroll with position: fixed.

Once I scrolled, I realize it was stuck in the fixed position. When I changed it to position: sticky so that it scrolls with the nav bar as the page is scrolled, it now widens itself to the full length of the nav bar container and pushes content down on the page.

Here are some reference pictures. This is what I want it to look like, even when the page is scrolled:

[position: fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ2Df.png)

This is what it looks like when I change it to sticky. It scrolls with the page now as sticky, but it is the width of the page and pushes content down around it. This is NOT the behavior I want:

[position: sticky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9m2a.png)

I do not understand why it's doing this or how to fix it. I want it to scroll like sticky, but look like fixed. I hope this makes some sort of sense.

Here is the code:

```
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #1F2833;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include your HTML too, so that we can know the other elements that are living around your navbar and take a look at the full picture

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was with the nav bar itself. It now functions as intended. These needed to be added to the nav bar (submenu).

**overflow: visible;**

**display: inline-block;**

Position needed to be set to absolute in drop down (dropdown-content):

**position: absolute;**

```
.submenu {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #1F2833;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1F2833;
    z-index: 1;
}
```